# resize and position all the elements in a DIV to match the new dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

on my website, I have a div containing lots of elements. The elements are positioned by  coordinates in px and not %.

The div has height = 1000px and width = 1000px;

on a button click I am resizing the Div to be 500px X 500px;

Is there a way I can also resize all the elements inside it without having to go through each one and figure out what the new size and position of each should be? And Also I need to do it without using percentages.

I'm just asking if this is possible or looking for hints or tips to do it.

Thanks

Comment: As your measurement will be exactly half the current measurement you could use jQuery to half the height and width of all contained elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should have used relative measurements to start with :)

Here is some example code on how to do this "the ugly way", with jQuery:

```
$('#container div') // your selector here
    .each(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        var p = t.position();
        t.css({
            left: ~~(p.left * .5),      // ~~ is for flooring
            top: ~~(p.top * .5),        // you could do x / 2 instead of * .5
            height: ~~(t.height() * .5),
            width: ~~(t.width() * .5)
        });
    });
```

An alternative might be to use the CSS selector of your container to state some alternate measurements and coordinates for the divs inside of it. Here's an example:

```
#container { ... }
#container div { position: absolute; }
#container .myDiv1 { left: 40px; top: 40px; height: 100px; width: 100px; }
#container:hover .myDiv1 { left: 20px; top: 20px; height: 50px; width: 50px; }
```